# Cakephp problem with Save belongsTo

Tags: cakephp

I got problem when save belongto

```
class Script extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Script';
    var $belongsTo = array(
    'ScriptCatagories' => array(
        'className' => 'ScriptCatagories',
        'foreignKey' => 'script_catagories_id',

 function add_script() {
   pr($this->data);
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Script->create();
        $this->data['Script']['script_catagories_id'] = $this->Script->scriptCategory->id;
        $this->data['Script']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        if ($this->Script->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The script has been saved', true));
             $this->redirect(array('action' => 'script_index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The script could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }

     pr($scriptCatagories = $this->Script->ScriptCatagories->find('list')); 
     $this->set(compact('scriptCatagories'));
}
```

when click save

```
Array
(
[Script] => Array
    (
        [name] => fdfvvds
        [description] => dfvdfvdfvdf
        [tags] => 
     )
   )
    Array
   (
    [0] => performance
    [1] => cleanup
    )
```

question in

```
        $this->data['Script']['script_catagories_id'] = $this->Script->scriptCategory->id;
```

I need to save categoryid to script table but I don't know to get  it
  thank you

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var $belongsTo = array(
> 'ScriptCatagories' => array(
>     'className' => 'ScriptCatagories',
>     'foreignKey' => 'script_catagories_id',
> ```

first, it doesn't have close parentheses. And it should be singular ScriptCategory, also the foreign key script_category_id (just to follow the convention). And you misspelled category (you have `$this->Script->scriptCategory->id;` later in the code)

Comment: sorry in question but in real code  is complete but in question I lost it